# EditText: Toggle InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've created a custom `EditText` by extending `android.widget.EditText`.

I would like to have the auto correct spans only visible, when the `EditText` has focus. So I call `setInputType(INPUT_NO_FOCUS);` in the constructor and:

```
@Override
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    if (focused) {
        setInputType(INPUT_FOCUS);
    } else {
        setInputType(INPUT_NO_FOCUS);
    }
}
```

with:

```
private final int INPUT_NO_FOCUS = TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE
        | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS;
private final int INPUT_FOCUS = TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE
        | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLET;
```

==> There is indeed no auto correction and auto complete, but it does not appear after clicking on the `EditText`. Input type is changed successfully.

**How can I trigger the auto correction/ add auto completion?**

//Edit:

User Case I want to archive:

1. `MyEditText extends EditText` view is displayed and not focused. There is no spell checking on the text (--> No red spans/lines under the text)
2. User clicks into the edit field to. --> Spell checking gets triggered --> Red lines appear (User can click on wrong spelled words and let the OS correct them)
3. User clicks on another View element --> Red lines/spans disappear.

Comment: can you please make the question more clear.. if possible with images

Comment: Added a Use Case Scenario

Comment: :( cant visualize your cases completely as i didnt work on autocorrect. you can try one thing call invalidate() method after setinputtype

Comment: invalidate() did not work...

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there's no good way to do this.  The problem is that the Android framework doesn't really have a mechanism to tell the keyboard when the input type has changed.  A keyboard generally checks the type when the field opens.  After that, if the type changes it won't know unless it polls for it, and I don't think any existing keyboard does that.

Answer (score 0):

Override this method in MyEditText class
`@Override
    protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
        super.onTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter);
        setInputType(INPUT_FOCUS);
    }`

Using this method you can change the inputType of EditText to INPUT_FOCUS that show red line under text when user edit text of MyEditText

Comment: I've tried it but still the correction spell gets not triggered